# Getting wrong array length with jQuery and mysqli_num_rows()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm adding new data to database table with jQuery. Then i'm getting all content from that table. Problem is i'm getting wrong array size every odd time.If i refresh the page it's getting right array size but when i'm clicking button with jQuery function it's all messed up.

I figure out that

```
 $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

already return wrong num of rows

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getallentries = function(){
        $.getJSON("entries.php",{action : "getall"},function(data) {
            var content_array = $.map(data, function(e) { return e;});   
            console.log(content_array.length); // to check array size
        });

        $.addstatic = function(){
            $.post("entries.php",{action : "addstatic"});
        };

    };

    $("#adds").on("click",function(){
        $.addstatic();  
        $.getallentries();
    });

    $.getallentries();
```

And here is entries.php:

```
function getall(){

    $link = db_connect(); 
    $query= "SELECT * FROM jq";

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);// Smart people said MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT should help but it didn't

    $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    for($i = 0 ;$i<$n;$i++)
        {
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $b[]=$row;
        }


    echo json_encode(array($b));  

}

function addstatic(){
    $link = db_connect(); 
    $statin_Entry = "Static Entry";
    $query = "INSERT INTO jq (Entry) VALUES ('$statin_Entry')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

}   

if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    switch($action) {
    case 'getall' : getall(); break;
    }
}
else {
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch($action) {
        case 'addstatic' : addstatic();break;
        case 'removelast' : removelast();break;
            // ...etc...
        }
    }
}
```

This is log of array length
[image: This is log of array length]

So the problem again, same array size 143,146,151 and where is 156??

Comment: You're calling `$.getallentries()` before the AJAX call in `$.addstatic()` has completed, so the database hasn't updated yet. Remember, AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? Is the definition of `$.addstatic` really supposed to be inside the definition of `$.getallentries`?

Comment: Somene who said you about MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT is not that smart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `$.getallentries` in the callback function of the `$.addstatic` AJAX call, so that it runs after `$.addstatic` has finished updating the database.

```
    $.addstatic = function(){
        $.post("entries.php",{action : "addstatic"}, $.getallentries);
    };
```

There's no need to use `mysqli_num_rows` before fetching the rows. You should use a loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $b[] = $row;
}
```

Also, you're wrapping your array in another array. Just do:

```
echo json_encode($b);
```

The way you've written it, `console.log(content_array.length)` should always log `1`, I don't understand how you're getting higher numbers. Are you sure you posted the actual code?

There's no point in use `$.map`, all it's doing is making a copy of the `data` array. Just use `data` itself.

And in your PHP, you don't need to test both `isset()` and `!empty()`, because `empty()` checks if the variable is set first.

You don't need to use `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT`, it's the default for that option.

Comment: Why use `setTimeout` when you can do it correctly as I showed?